# Responsive 3 column html email layout last column image is one pixel too high in gmail and outlook

Tags: email, gmail, html-email, responsive

I have a 3 column responsive email layout (code is below). This works almost perfectly. It shows well on mobile and even in outlook desktop client. But for some reason, the last image is one pixel too tall in Gmail and Outlook.com. I know this is probably because of the 100% width, but does anyone know how to fix it? You'll see that I even set pixel widths and heights on my images, but because the container has 100% width, I think that is causing it to fail. Any hacks for this?

I've added the image and a Photoshop guide and you can clearly see that the last one extends one pixel below the others.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;">
                            <tr>
                                <td>



                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top" class="responsive-td block3up" style="width: 180px; padding-right: 5px;padding-left:10px;">
                                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%;" class="stylingblock-content-wrapper">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner">
                                                            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center"><img data-assetid="84953" src="http://image.e-mail.visitorlando.com/lib/fe9a13727465007874/m/2/4adc30d0-46be-4e10-bdd5-b28937548ba4.jpg" height="120" width="180" style="display: block; padding: 0px 0px 10px; text-align: center; height: auto; width: 100%; border: 0px;"></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%; margin: 0px;" class="stylingblock-content-wrapper">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="padding: 10px 0px;" class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner">
                                                            <i><a alias="" class="blockme" conversion="false" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.visitorlando.com/blog/index.cfm/2018/1/17/Free-Resources-for-Planning-Your-Next-Orlando-Vacation/" style="color:#808080;text-decoration:none;" title="">Free Resources for a Perfect Orlando Holiday</a></i>
                                                            <div style="font-size:12px;padding:10px 0 10px;margin-top:10px;">
                                                                <span class="blockme2">Whether it&rsquo;s your first trip to Orlando or you&rsquo;re coming back for more, Visit Orlando has free, trusted resources designed to help you plan your perfect Orlando holiday, including our Official Visitor Center, Live Chat assistance, an innovative mobile app and much more!</span></div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                            <td valign="top" class="responsive-td block3up" style="width: 180px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;">
                                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner">
                                                            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center"><img data-assetid="84871" src="http://image.e-mail.visitorlando.com/lib/fe9a13727465007874/m/2/0739b042-e92e-42a9-b294-9be63f8a3000.jpg" height="120" width="180" style="display: block; padding: 0px 0px 10px; text-align: center; height: auto; width: 100%; border: 0px;"></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%; margin: 0px;" class="stylingblock-content-wrapper">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="padding: 10px 0px;" class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><i><a alias="" class="blockme" conversion="false" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.visitorlando.com/discounts-and-tickets/" style="color:#808080;text-decoration:none;" title="">Save Big With Orlando Deals &amp; Discounts</a></i>
                                                            <div style="font-size:12px;padding:10px 0 10px;margin-top:10px;">
                                                                <span class="blockme2">Not only is Visit Orlando a trusted source for discounted tickets to the world&rsquo;s most popular theme parks and attractions, but we&rsquo;re also your source for bargains throughout the destination. Save on resorts, dining, shopping and everything else you&rsquo;ll want to do in Orlando!</span></div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                            <td valign="top" class="responsive-td block3up" style="width: 180px; padding-left: 5px;padding-right:10px;">
                                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%; " class="stylingblock-content-wrapper">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner">
                                                            <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td align="center"><img data-assetid="84872" src="http://image.e-mail.visitorlando.com/lib/fe9a13727465007874/m/2/db9decce-c593-4bbd-a3c2-e819df747c47.jpg" height="120" width="180" style="display: block; padding: 0px 0px 10px; text-align: center; height: auto; width: 100%; border: 0px;"></td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="min-width: 100%; margin: 0px;" class="stylingblock-content-wrapper">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td style="padding: 10px 0px;" class="stylingblock-content-wrapper camarker-inner"><i><a alias="" class="blockme" conversion="false" data-linkto="http://" href="http://www.visitorlando.com/blog/index.cfm/2018/2/07/Have-a-Blast-at-the-Newest-Attractions-in-Orlando" style="color:#808080;text-decoration:none;" title="">Blast Off With Orlando&rsquo;s Newest Thrills</a></i>
                                                            <div style="font-size:12px;padding:10px 0 10px;margin-top:10px;">
                                                                <span class="blockme2">Orlando is constantly improving. In fact, we added so many new attractions in 2017 that, even if you&rsquo;ve visited recently, you probably haven&rsquo;t seen them all &mdash; starting with all-new thrills at Walt Disney World Resort, Universal Orlando Resort, SeaWorld Orlando and LEGOLAND Florida Resort!</span></div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>



                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
```

And here is the CSS in the head tag

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
      ReadMsgBody{ width: 100%;}
      .ExternalClass {width: 100%;}
      .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;}
      body {-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;margin:0 !important;}
      p { margin: 1em 0;}
      table td { border-collapse: collapse;}
      img {outline:0;}
      a img {border:none;}
      p {margin: 1em 0;}
      @-ms-viewport{ width: device-width;}
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
      @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .container {width: 100% !important;}
        .footer { width:auto !important; margin-left:0; }
        .content-padding{ padding:4px !important; }
        .mobile-hidden { display:none !important; }
        .logo { display:block !important; padding:0 !important; }
        img { max-width:100% !important; height:auto !important; max-height:auto !important;}
        .header img{max-width:100% !important;height:auto !important; max-height:auto !important;}
        .photo img { width:100% !important; max-width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}
        .drop { display:block !important; width: 100% !important; float:left; clear:both;}
        .footerlogo { display:block !important; width: 100% !important; padding-top:15px; float:left; clear:both;}
        .nav4, .nav5, .nav6 { display: none !important; }
        .tableBlock {width:100% !important;}
        .responsive-td {width:100% !important; display:block !important; padding:0 !important; }
        .fluid, .fluid-centered {
          width: 100% !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          height: auto !important;
          margin-left: auto !important;
          margin-right: auto !important;
        }
        .fluid-centered {
          margin-left: auto !important;
          margin-right: auto !important;
        }
        /* MOBILE GLOBAL STYLES - DO NOT CHANGE */
body, .tb_properties{font-family: Arial !important; font-size: 25px !important; color: #808080 !important; line-height: 1.5 !important; padding: 0px !important; }.buttonstyles{font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif !important; font-size: 16px !important; color: #FFFFFF !important; padding: 10px !important; }h1{font-family: Arial !important; font-size: 28px !important; color: #202020 !important; line-height: 1 !important; }h2{font-family: Arial !important; font-size: 20px !important; color: #202020 !important; line-height: 1 !important; }h3{font-family: Arial !important; font-size: 18px !important; color: #202020 !important; line-height: 1 !important; }a:not(.buttonstyles){line-height: 1 !important; }.mobile-hidden{display: none !important; }


/* END OF MOBILE GLOBAL STYLES - DO NOT CHANGE */
         .block3up { padding: 20px !important;background:#efefef;}
        .blockme2{font-size:22px !important;}
        .blockme{font-size:25px !important;}
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
        .container { width:100% !important; }
        .mobile-hidden { display:none !important; }
        .logo { display:block !important; padding:0 !important; }
        .photo img { width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}
        .nav5, .nav6 { display: none !important;}
        .fluid, .fluid-centered {
          width: 100% !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          height: auto !important;
          margin-left: auto !important;
          margin-right: auto !important;
        }
        .fluid-centered {
          margin-left: auto !important;
          margin-right: auto !important;
        }
      }


    </style>
    <!--[if mso]>
      <style type="text/css">
          /* Begin Outlook Font Fix */
          body, table, td {
              font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
              font-size:16px;
              color:#808080;
              line-height:1;
          }
          /* End Outlook Font Fix */
      </style>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `height: auto;` and add `max-height: 120px;` from your `img` style sheet. Your problem will be resolved.

I might recommend checking your full email in a testing service like Litmus or Campaign Monitor. Currently what you're showing is not responsive and strange things happen to the tables and images depending on the web client used to view them.

If you are doing responsive, add `max-height` to the `@media` query to fine-tune the output.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks @gwally I'll try it. There is more code in the email that I'm not showing and I am testing in Litmus as well

Comment: would I add max-height to the media query for mobile only?

Comment: It's actually displaying fine on mobile, and your solution worked in gmail without adding it to the media query, so is it really necessary?

Comment: @garek007 You didn't post your html code, so I didn't know if it was needed for media queries.

Comment: @garek007 Your template isn't really responsive. Since you have the primary table set at `width: 100%` (line 97), you should add `width="600"` to the table. What is happening is that your table is taking up 100% of the viewport, your images are being stretched because the style is set to be `width: 100%;` If you set the table width correctly and change the width style to `width: 180px;`, it will improve the overall quality of the email.

Comment: Thanks @gwally, the funny thing is, this is the code that Salesforce Marketing Cloud provides for their responsive emails. Crazy that it's not done better!